# re groupdict: Is it possible to specify the value type?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex to decompose a Tyre spec in sub elements which needs to be returned as a dict. Its numeric elements need to be returned as int.

Here is an input example:

```
tyre_specs = '255/45W17'
```

The desired output:

```
tyre_details = {'width': 255, 'profile': 45, 'rating': 'W', 'rim': 17}
```

I capture each element using a regular expression pattern with named capture which are matching the desired output dict keys. I then use groupdict to generate my output dict. However, all the values are strings. So I need to further process the relevant values to cast them as int.

My function, see below, works. However I was wondering if is there a better way to do this. Is there for instance a way to enforce the type of some specific matching groups?

If not, is this approach "pythonic"?

Here is my function

```
import re

def tyre_details(tyre_size):
    pattern = r'(?P<width>\d{3})\/(?P<profile>\d{2})(?P<rating>[A-Z]{1,2})(?P<rim>\d{2})'
    try:
        details = re.match(pattern, tyre_size).groupdict()
    except AttributeError:
        raise ValueError('Input does not conform to the usual tyre size nomenclature "Width/ProfileRatingRim"')

    int_keys = set('width profile rim'.split())
    for key in int_keys:
        details[key] = int(details[key])
    return details
```

Edit:

1. Added handling exception for when the input string doesn't match. I raise this as a value error
2. defined the keys to be casted as a set instead of list.
3. removed redundant try/except clause.

Comment: Regex is only working with string/byte data, you should cast it to a numeric type explicitly yourself.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, this is what I thought  when going through the doc. i wanted to check if I didn't miss something.

Comment: @alfajet, 1) check for false matches is required 2) `int_keys` is better defined as a sequence

Comment: Use `str.isdigit()` to check if the string is a number and then convert it to int

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Thanks for the recommendations. I have implemented them.

Comment: @igorkf: Thanks. I am following the "Easier to ask for forgiveness" principle by casting the string to int in a try/except clause instead of testing first.

Comment: You do not need any `isdigit` check since your group patterns are `\d{x,y}`, that only matches digits. You do not need any try/except in these cases. Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` if you are afraid there can be any Hindi digits in the input. Or compile the pattern with `re.A` / `re.ASCII` flag.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor indeed this try/except clause was redundant as the regex only captures digits anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first check if the regex matched. If it did, then the `match.groups()` can be dereferenced directly into variables and used to build the final dictionary object:

```
import re

def tyre_details(tyre_size):
    pattern  = r'(\d{3})/(\d{2})([A-Z]{1,2})(\d{2})'
    m = re.match(pattern, tyre_size)
    details = {}
    if m:
        width, profile, rating, rim = m.groups()
        details = {"width": int(width), "profile": int(profile), "rating": rating, "rim": int(rim)}
    return details

tyre_specs = '255/45W17'
print( tyre_details(tyre_specs) )
# => {'width': 255, 'profile': 45, 'rating': 'W', 'rim': 17}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CVvGYA)

There is no need for named groups with this approach, and you do not need any `try/except` or other checks when casting `str` to `int` because the groups in question only match digits, see `(\d{3})`, `(\d{2})` and `(\d{2})`.

If you need a full string match, replace `re.match` with `re.fullmatch`, and in case the match can appear anywhere in the string, use `re.search`.

Note `/` is not any special regex metacharacter, do not escape it in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for this great answer. I tried using groupdict as it seemed to fit with my requirement but I need to further process it afterwards. Your code is definitely easier to read. Regarding escaping `/` that's a old habit I got from `sed "s/find/replace"` where `/` needs to be escaped.

Comment: @alfajet Hm, I use `s,find,replace,`, `s|find|replace|` and do not have to escape `/` :)